# OpenGL crashing with current code (followed from book)

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, glfw

[Picture of program running with current code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YYUfU.png)I am trying to create a simple shader program (4.4). But whatever I do, My window just appears white and loading forever... So my problem is that my program seems to crash when I try to load anything from my two files (which are in the same directory as my main.cpp)

Code is running fine with no apparent issues:

```
#include <GL\glew.h>
#include <GLFW\glfw3.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

#define numVAOs 1

GLuint renderingProgram;
GLuint vao[numVAOs];

void printShaderLog(GLuint shader) {
    int len = 0;
    int chWrittn = 0;
    char* log;
    glGetShaderiv(shader, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &len);

    if (len > 0) {
        log = (char*)malloc(len);
        glGetShaderInfoLog(shader, len, &chWrittn, log);
        cout << "Shader Info Log: " << log << endl;
        free(log);
    }
}

void printProgramLog(int prog) {
    int len = 0;
    int chrWrittn = 0;
    char* log;
    glGetProgramiv(prog, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &len);

    if (len > 0) {
        log = (char*)malloc(len);
        glGetProgramInfoLog(prog, len, &chrWrittn, log);
        cout << "Program Info Log: " << log << endl;
        free(log);
    }
}

bool checkOpenGLError() {
    bool foundError = false;
    int glErr = glGetError();
    while (glErr != GL_NO_ERROR) {
        cout << "glError: " << glErr << endl;
        foundError = true;
        glErr = glGetError();
    }
    return foundError;
}

string readShaderSource(const char* filePath) {
    string content;
    ifstream fileStream(filePath, ios::in);
    string line = "";

    while (!fileStream.eof()) {
        getline(fileStream, line);
        content.append(line + "\n");
    }
    fileStream.close();
    return content;
}

GLuint createShaderProgram() {
    GLint vertCompiled;
    GLint fragCompiled;
    GLint linked;
    //const char* vshaderSource =
    //  "#version 430    \n"
    //  "void main(void) \n"
    //  "{gl_Position = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);}";
    //
    //const char* fshaderSource =
    //  "#version 430    \n"
    //  "out vec4 color; \n"
    //  "void main(void) \n"
    //  "{ if (gl_FragCoord.x > 300) color = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0); else color = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 
    1.0, 1.0);}";

    string vertShader = readShaderSource("vshader.glsl");
    string fragShader = readShaderSource("fshader.glsl");
    cout << vertShader << endl;
    cout << fragShader << endl;

    const char* vertShaderSrc = vertShader.c_str();
    const char* fragShaderSrc = fragShader.c_str();


    GLuint vShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    GLuint fShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);

    glShaderSource(vShader, 1, &vertShaderSrc, NULL);

    glShaderSource(fShader, 1, &fragShaderSrc, NULL);
    glCompileShader(vShader);
    checkOpenGLError();
    glGetShaderiv(vShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &vertCompiled);

    if (vertCompiled != 1) {
        cout << "vertex compilation failed" << endl;
        printShaderLog(vShader);
    }

    glCompileShader(fShader);
    checkOpenGLError();
    glGetShaderiv(fShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &fragCompiled);

    if (fragCompiled != 1) {
        cout << "fragment compilation failed" << endl;
        printShaderLog(fShader);
    }
    GLuint vfProgram = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(vfProgram, vShader);
    glAttachShader(vfProgram, fShader);
    glLinkProgram(vfProgram);
    checkOpenGLError();
    glGetProgramiv(vfProgram, GL_LINK_STATUS, &linked);

    if (linked != 1) {
        cout << "linking failed" << endl;
        printProgramLog(vfProgram);
    }

    return vfProgram;
}

void init(GLFWwindow* window) {
    renderingProgram = createShaderProgram();
    glGenVertexArrays(numVAOs, vao);
    glBindVertexArray(vao[0]);
}
void display(GLFWwindow* window, double currentTime) {
    glUseProgram(renderingProgram);
    glPointSize(230.0f);
    glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, 1);
}
int main(void) {
    if (!glfwInit()) { exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 4);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(600, 600, "Chapter2 - program1", NULL, NULL);
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK) { exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }
    glfwSwapInterval(1);
    init(window);
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
        display(window, glfwGetTime());
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }
    glfwDestroyWindow(window);
    glfwTerminate();
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: You never gall `glfwSwapBuffers`, so whatever you render won't ever appear. YOu also never call `glClear` so your color buffer contents are undefined anyway. You also attempt to draw 1 point without ever setting up the vertex attrib arrays.

Comment: @derhass `glfwSwapBuffers` is actually being called :)

Comment: Wow, how did I miss that? Whatever, this code is still horrbily lacking.

Comment: So as I said, I am very new to this, so what is it, that are lacking so much in the code @derhass because i just want to know how it can be done better, or what i need to be aware of

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing these two lines of code in the main loop. The first one sets the color of the "environment" or "background".  The second one clears the screen and the depth buffer before each frame.

`glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);`

`glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );`

Comment: Hey. Thanks for your answer and explaination for what the lines do. Sadly my code still will not display anything and is still just loading with a white screen.

Comment: @ThobiasLarsen The code itself looks fine, is it possible that your program can't find the shader files? That would cause an issue like yours, If you are using visual studio, you should set the working directory to $(ProjectDir).

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation, but it is set to projectDir sadly. So still might be a problem reading the files, but i dont know how. maybe i placed the files in a wrong place or something?

Comment: @ThobiasLarsen Projectdir means the folder containing the .vcxproj files, if the shader files are not in that folder, try moving them to that folder. You may have to explore your directory a bit to find it. (it is not immediately obvious)

Comment: damn, you are right. i had it one folder out, so it did not work, damn it actually runs now. thank you so much. you saved my OpenGL learning!

Comment: Glad I could be of aid :)

Answer (score 1):

As @derhass pointed out, you're missing a `glClear()` (junked the shader loader):

[image: screenshot]

```
// g++ main.cpp `pkg-config --cflags --libs glew glfw3`
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <iostream>

void CheckStatus( GLuint obj, bool isShader )
{
    GLint status = GL_FALSE, log[ 1 << 11 ] = { 0 };
    ( isShader ? glGetShaderiv : glGetProgramiv )( obj, isShader ? GL_COMPILE_STATUS : GL_LINK_STATUS, &status );
    if( status == GL_TRUE ) return;
    ( isShader ? glGetShaderInfoLog : glGetProgramInfoLog )( obj, sizeof( log ), NULL, (GLchar*)log );
    std::cerr << (GLchar*)log << "\n";
    std::exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
}

void AttachShader( GLuint program, GLenum type, const char* src )
{
    GLuint shader = glCreateShader( type );
    glShaderSource( shader, 1, &src, NULL );
    glCompileShader( shader );
    CheckStatus( shader, true );
    glAttachShader( program, shader );
    glDeleteShader( shader );
}

const char* const vert = R"GLSL(
#version 430
void main()
{
    gl_Position = vec4( 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 );
}
)GLSL";

const char* const frag = R"GLSL(
#version 430
out vec4 color;
void main()
{
    if( gl_FragCoord.x > 300 )
        color = vec4( 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 );
    else
        color = vec4( 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0 );
}
)GLSL";

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    if( !glfwInit() )
    {
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }
    glfwWindowHint( GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 4 );
    glfwWindowHint( GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3 );
    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow( 600, 600, "GLFW", NULL, NULL );
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    if( glewInit() != GLEW_OK )
    {
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }
    glfwSwapInterval(1);

    GLuint prog = glCreateProgram();
    AttachShader( prog, GL_VERTEX_SHADER, vert );
    AttachShader( prog, GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, frag );
    glLinkProgram( prog );
    CheckStatus( prog, false );
    glUseProgram( prog );

    GLuint vao = 0;
    glGenVertexArrays( 1, &vao );
    glBindVertexArray( vao );

    while( !glfwWindowShouldClose( window ) )
    {
        glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
        glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );

        glUseProgram( prog );
        glPointSize( 230.0f );
        glDrawArrays( GL_POINTS, 0, 1 );
        glfwSwapBuffers( window );
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    glfwDestroyWindow( window );
    glfwTerminate();
    exit( EXIT_SUCCESS );
}
```